# How to figure out, why a TestNG Suite skips a certain test?

Tags: java, testng

We have different testng test suites defined:

- quality-gate-1 - group "unit"
- quality-gate-2 - group "integration-must"
- quality-gate-3 - group "integration-should"
- quality-gate-4 - group "performance"
- up-to-quality-gate 2 - groups "unit,integration-must"
- up-to-quality-gate 3 - groups
  "unit,integration-must,integration-should"
- up-to-quality-gate 4 - groups
  "unit-integration-must,integration-should,performance"

and stumbled on a problem recently. A test that is in the group integration-must gets executed with the suits for "quality-gate-2" and "up-to-quality-gate-2". But it doesn´t in the "up-to quality-gate-3" suite. There is no error in the log. The verbose level of the suite is set to 10.

I double checked the suites and groups, everything should be ok. The Test itself has a dependsOnMethods annotation. The method it depends on hast the same group and therefore runs in the same suit. This method gets executed like expected in all the 3 cases above.

I´m looking for a way to analyze this further. Is there a way to get more Information what goes wrong here?

Comment: If html report is getting generated 'test-output/index.html' Info - < groups .Is it showing the method which is not executed for "up-to-quality-gate 3 - groups "unit,integration-must,integration-should"

Comment: Yes the method is shown in testng-results.xml in group integration-must. But it is not executed.

Comment: When you say its not getting executed. Is it getting skipped or there are no logs at all .

Comment: There are no logs for this test in the test section of the testng-results.xml. It is not getting skipped.